# Alfresco conent store deletion

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I have conentstore configured in below content store location.

D:\alfresco-content-services\alf_data\contentstore**2019**

I want to delete above shown 2019 folder under conentstore. I dont need 2019 anymore. Basically purging .

If i delete files above folder ,will it clean-up the metadata and indexes also ?

or will it corrupt my respository ? Whats the best way to achive mass deletion , which will delete references in database also without corrupting repo ?

Thanks & Regards
Brijesh

Comment: You should never touch the files in the content store directory directly. Treat that entire directory like a black box. If you want to purge content, use the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete any folder from the content store, it will not affect the database (and hence the indexes) in any way. You will end up with nodes referencing .bin files that do not exist anymore, though.

Note, if that folder is the first year in your content store, then it also contains some files used by Alfresco to determine if the content store matches the database. Depending on this, if you delete the folder - you will mess up Alfresco (repository will not start if it does not find those files).

Mass deletion in general is tricky, I'd suggest using Bulk Import Tool's delete web script that does this as fast as possible (avoids audit logs, recycle bin, etc).